How to efficiently manage an API call inside NSManagedObjectContext.perform in swift?
So I have a function say 'sendData' that basically sends data to server by first fetching it from core data. Function can be called multiple times. So the basic structure is like this:
func sendData() {
     
     let context = CoreDataStack.defaultStack.newBackgroundContext

     let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<UserData> = UserData.fetchRequest()
     fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "shouldSendData == true")
     let records = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest)
     
     NetworkManager.shared.sendData(data: records) { res in
 
            for record in res {
                res.shouldSendData = false
            }
             CoreDataStack.saveContext(context, { (error) in
                 if error != nil {
                    print("Done")
                 }
             })
         }
     }
 }

If I use this approach, it basically works fine but as soon as I debug this by adding concurrency debug flag -com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1, it crashes on following line:

     let records = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest)


Now, to fix this, I have wrapped this whole function body in context.perform, and that seems to fix the issue. But I am confused into is this the right approach wrapping whole function in context.perform or should I keep API call out of it? What's the downfall to this approach?
I am worried as whether this can cause incorrect and mistimed async calls or not.
Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

If you can use async/await, you can do let records = await context.perform { try? context.fetch(fetchRequest) }, which is the cleaner way, else, you need to use indeed embed the call inside perform... You could use performAndWait too: var records: [UserData]?; context.performAndWait { records = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest) } But performAndWait could causes deadlocks depending on how you call them...
